# How can I have the state of a UISwitch be reflected across all my view controllers?

Tags: ios, storyboard, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I use storyboards with different views, and in a settings view I have a UISwitch. I want this switch to affect the state of all my different views. For example: if the switch is turned off in the settings view, then there will be no sound in the play view. How can the state of the switch be saved?

I have searched, and in many places it's said that you have to use NSUserDefaults for this, but I don´t understand completely how that works. What kind of code do I have to write in the .m/.h/appdelegate.h/m etc.?

Comment: In this link you will find a tutorial that might be useful: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/08/application-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the preference value (eg. sound off) in user defaults when user activate the switch. Then get the value in other view controllers' viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear method to guarantee the persistence.

Check apple's document about [Preferences and Settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i).

Answer (score 0):

After a quick read-through, it seems fairly simple.

You would first create a new local NSUserObject:

```
NSUserDefaults *d = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

You would then assign to it a value from any of the views, in this case I would assume a BOOL would suffice:

```
[d setBool:TRUE forKey:@"switchBOOL"]; 
//the key be understood by you and describes the switch
```

And in viewWillLoad of your other views retrieve the value:

```
NSUserDefaults *d = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[d boolForKey:@"switchBOOL"];
```

Comment: where am I supposed to write those lines of code? Is that enough to solve my problem? i´m newbie in programming..

Comment: That's not really a question I can answer. I would advise against setting the value in the app delegate. I would assume in ViewDidLoad of the view storyboard pushes to first.